# jQuery Cycle Plugin - Dictate locaton of thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle-plugin

What I would like to do is dictate where my thumbnails are instead of using the main images as the thumbnail.

I'm pretty sure this can be done, I just need a little push in the right direction.

Here is my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$('#imageContainer').before('').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  2000, 
    timeout: 8000, 
    pager:  '#nav',

```
// callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i, slide) { 
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="121" height="67" /></a></li>'; 
}
```

});

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="imageContainer">
    <img src="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/1.jpg"  rel="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/1t.jpg" width="378" height="210" />
    <img src="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/2.jpg" rel="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/2t.jpg" width="378" height="210" />
    <img src="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/3.jpg" rel="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/3t.jpg" width="378" height="210" />
</div>
<div id="nav"></div>
```

Any help would do.

thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a scenario like the one described here http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager2.html, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(id, slide) { 
    var thumb_prefix = "t_";
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + thumb_prefix + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
}
```

This is the simplest example, of course you can do something different depending on your naming convention and particular application, for example inserting a t at the end before the extension:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(id, slide) { 

    // Split off the filename with no extension (period + 3 letter extension)
    var new_src = slide.src.substring(0,slide.src.length-4);

    // Add the "t"
    new_src += "t";

    // Add the period and the 3 letter extension back on
    new_src += slide.src.substring(slide.src.length-4,slide.src.length);

    // Set this as the source for our image
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + new_src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! If I could ask one more question.

I would like to add this "t" to the end of the file src for example:

Before adding "t":
<img src="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/1.jpg" width="378" height="210" />

After adding "t":
<img src="http://www.ifcj.org/ifcj-08/images/elements/slideshow/1t.jpg" width="378" height="210" />

Comment: Okay thay didn't come out right.

I need to add this "t" to the image src path but before the image extension so it reads as such: /1t.jpg

Comment: Hey one last question I know that you have helped me out here a lot but wanted to know how I can go about adding links to the large images. Using the onAfter function is the way... but i'm not seeing a solid example. So if anyone can point me in the right way that would be great. thanks!