# Insert "t" into an images path using JQuery

Tags: jquery, insert

What I would like to do is insert a "t" into the path of the image like so:

```
<img src="../images/elements/slideshow/1t.jpg"  width="378" height="210" />
```

A little look at my script:

```
var thumb_prefix = "t";
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + thumb_prefix + '" width="121" height="67" /></a></li>';
```

This is just adding a "t" to the end of the path.

Any help would do thank you!

Comment: Do you want to add a 't' to all image paths on the current page ?

Comment: Yeah... thats what our naming convention is. The question I now have is can we also add links to the large image being displayed to take us to the page that the image is describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, this is answered here [jQuery Cycle Plugin - Dictate locaton of thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948903/jquery-cycle-plugin-dictate-locaton-of-thumbnails/1948982)

Basically as follows -- slide.src is your old source, and new_src is the resulting new source for the image.

```
// Split off the filename with no extension (period + 3 letter extension)
var new_src = slide.src.substring(0,slide.src.length-4);

// Add the "t"
new_src += "t";

// Add the period and the 3 letter extension back on
new_src += slide.src.substring(slide.src.length-4,slide.src.length);

return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + new_src + '" width="121" height="67" /></a></li>';
```

Additionally, don't forget to change width / height values above to whatever the new values should be.

Comment: Okay I promise this is the last question.

I would like the to add a link to each and every large image that gets displayed during the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what’s going on in your script, but if all your images’ file names end in `.jpg`, then you can use the JavaScript `replace` function, like this:

```
$('img').attr('src', function(){this.src.replace('.jpg', 't.jpg')})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(
    function(){
        p = $(this).attr('src');
        newp = p.replace('.jpg','t.jpg');
        $(this).attr('src',newp);
    }
);
```

That code will turn this:

```
<img src="../images/elements/slideshow/1.jpg"  width="378" height="210" />
```

Into this:

```
<img src="../images/elements/slideshow/1t.jpg"  width="378" height="210" />
```

**Edit:**
Obviously, that selector will make the change to every single image in the document, so you will probably want to change it to only change the images you want changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  img.attr('src', img.attr('src').replace(/(\.[^\.]*$|$)/, thumb_prefix + '$&'));
}
```

This will add the value of `thumb_prefix` to the filename portion of the `src` attribute of each `img`.

It should work with any file extension (or even files with no extension).

Comment: Thanks I will take a look doing this also