# Jquery Cycle Plugin set thumbnail location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle, cycle-plugin

First off, my question is really similar to a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948903/jquery-cycle-plugin-dictate-locaton-of-thumbnails), with the difference being I am using wordpess and the nextgen gallery plugin to manage my images, which writes images thumbnail images as such:

```
mygallery/image1.jpg
mygallery/image2.jpg
etc...
```

and thumbnails like this:

```
mygallery/thumbs/thumbs_image1.jpg
mygallery/thumbs/thumbs_image2.jpg
etc...
```

so what I am looking to do is set the source of the thumbnail.
Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$('#slideshow').after('').cycle({fx:'fade',speed:'slow',timeout: 0,pager: '#nav',

```
// callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is being worked on for the next version of NextGEN So I may just wait. Depending on your skill you could make a custom template.

See:
http://code.google.com/p/nextgen-gallery/issues/detail?id=294
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-feature-request-jquery-cycle-slideshow-option

Also, if you want to try to dig into the code check out this http://nextgen-gallery.com/templates/galleryview/ Didn't look to hard to customize I just don't have the time or need right now especially if it's going to be added soon.

Comment: yeah thanks, i see that... this is a custom template that i am making. it's isolating the source of the thumbnails that is required for it to work.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing you may be better off using a custom field type plugin.

Comment: what i am doing its pretty clear. i am looking to set the source of the thumbnails, and given the example linked, the best method would be using javascript. anyone?